# Edit error in ArcGis 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, editing, file-geodatabase

I am trying to create a feature in a polygon layer in a file geodatabase but I get this error:

`Create: An unexpected failure occurred.
The spatial index grid size is invalid.[test]
The spatial index grid size is invalid`

I can't figure out what my mistake?

update:

I can't delete this field in Arcatalog -- I  get this error:

`The ObjectID index cannot be deleted, it is a required index`

Comment: That is an attribute index, you need to recreate the *spatial* index

Comment: Please always provide error messages as text rather than pictures.

Comment: o.k i will fix it now.

Comment: You can leave images in, just make sure the error exists as text, so that text search can find it. Please do not include an "update" that changes the question -- Ask a new question (after doing appropriate research -- Since that message is quite explicit, I doubt it would require a question).  Case and punctuation matter for readability -- Please use proper English in your postings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close your Map Document, open the Feature Class properties in ArcCatalog.  In the FC Properties you can delete or recreate your spatial index.

From [Error: The spatial index grid size is invalid](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010090):

> If this error is encountered while editing within ArcMap, recalculate
> or modify the grid size of the feature class to accommodate the new
> feature. The recalculation of the grid size must be done from the
> Feature Class properties dialog box within ArcCatalog. This requires
> the use of the Stop Editing function, save any edits, and close the
> Map Document containing the feature class. For steps on how to
> recalculate or modify the grid size of a feature class, see the
> following Web help documentation: [Setting spatial indexes](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=2059&pid=2057&topicname=Setting_spatial_indexes).

From [Rebuild a spatial index](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/modifying-a-spatial-index.htm):

> To rebuild or re-create a spatial index on a feature class from the
> Feature Class Properties dialog box, do the following:
>
> 1. Start ArcMap and open the Catalog window or start ArcCatalog.
> 2. In the Catalog tree, connect to the geodatabase or database that contains the feature class for which you want to modify the spatial
>    index.   For enterprise geodatabases or databases, connect as the data
>    owner to rebuild indexes.
> 3. Right-click the feature class and click Properties.
> 4. Click the Indexes tab.
> 5. How you modify the spatial index for a feature class depends on what spatial data type the feature class contains.
>
>    - For feature classes using Geometry storage in SQL Server, click Recalculate to let ArcGIS set the grid size.
>    - For feature classes using ST_Geometry in Oracle, click Rebuild.
>    - For feature classes in any of the following, click Delete to drop the spatial index and click Create to create a new one:
>
>      - File geodatabases
>      - PostgreSQL
>      - DB2
>      - Informix
>      - Netezza
>      - ALTIBASE
>      - Teradata
>      - SQLite
>      - Microsoft Azure SQL Database
>      - Feature classes that use Geography or binary storage in SQL Server
>      - Feature classes that use binary or SDO_Geometry storage in Oracle
>
>    The re-created index reflects the current data.

Comment: i update my question